# Existence of a sequence of polynomials that approximate a holomorphic function uniformly on the closed unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $f:D(0,1) \to \mathbb C$ be continuous on the closed unit disc $D(0,1)$ and holomorphic on the open unit disc.

Show that there exist a sequence of polynomial that converge uniformly in the closed unit disc to $f$.

Any help please?

Comment: This seems false as stated. Try $f(z)=1/(1-z)$.

Comment: @Ted, I think perhaps $D(0,1)$ is intended to be the closed unit disk.  So your $f(z)$ is not continuous on $D(0,1)$.

Comment: @ Jair Taylor,effectively,$D(0,1)$ is the closed unit disc.

Comment: Mais remarquez bien que vous avez écrit "the open unit disk." So you mean continuous on the closed disc and holomorphic on the open? Your title and question are somewhat inconsistent and confusing. ;)

Comment: @Ted, thanks for the remark.I just corriged the question.

Comment: Hint: for each $n$, the function $f_n(z) = f((1-1/n)z)$ is holomorphic in a larger disk, and therefore can be uniformly approximated by polynomials on $D(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks you @JustABrickInTheWall